# ¿Cómo usar en este caso la función CONCAT de MYSQL en JAVA?

Tags: java, mysql, concat

Ya tengo una Jtable en la que aparecen todos mis usuarios de la base de datos, sin embargo, en  mi  tabla que se llama 'Usuarios' tengo en ella una columna llamada Estados en el que por defecto todos tienen un '1'(que significa que están activos), sin embargo, cuando un usuario es eliminado su Estado pasa a ser 0. Lo que quiero es que en mi Jtable solo aparezcan los usuarios que tengan Estado '1', pero no lo he logrado, no se si es porque estoy usando CONCAT y no me permite realizar esa condición.

Así es como lo tengo.

```
public void buscarusuarios(JTable table, String valueTosearch){

 Connection con = ConexionMySQL.getConnection();
 PreparedStatement ps;
    try {
        ps=con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM `usuario` WHERE CONCAT (`id_usu`, `nombre`, `apellido`, `num_documento`, `num_telefono`, `correo`, `contraseña`, `estado`, `genero`, `natalicio`, `tipo_documento`, `celular`, `idrol`, `idpermiso`) LIKE ? ");
        ps.setString(1, "%"+valueTosearch+"%");
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
        Object [] row;

        while(rs.next()){
            row= new Object [14];
            row[0]=rs.getInt(1);
                row[1]=rs.getString(2);
                  row[2]=rs.getString(3);
                    row[3]=rs.getString(4);
                      row[4]=rs.getString(5);
                        row[5]=rs.getString(6);
                          row[6]=rs.getString(7);
                            row[7]=rs.getString(8);
                              row[8]=rs.getString(9);
                                row[9]=rs.getString(10);
                                  row[10]=rs.getString(11);
                                    row[11]=rs.getString(12);



                         model.addRow(row);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MtdUsuario.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Ya he intentado  colocar en el LIke un '1' pero no sirve me dice

```
Mar 31, 2020 9:03:19 AM metodo.MtdUsuario buscarusuarios
GRAVE: null

java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).}
```

GRACIAS POR SU AYUDA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remueve el CONCAT y solo usa la condición `estado like ?`

```
SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE estado LIKE ?
```

Y quita los comodines `%%` al valor del parámetro:

```
ps.setString(1, valueTosearch);
```

Comment: Hola, te comento que probe lo que me dijiste pero sigue apareciendo los usuarios con Estado 1 y 0 .

Comment: Ya actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo unico malo es que toca colocar un 1 en el buscador para que aparezcan los resultados pero ahora me toca ver a mi que puedo hacer. Muchas gracias me haz quitado un peso de encima